# How to remove MDBootstrap a class defult selecte color

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, frontend, mdbootstrap

I'm using [MDBootstrap](https://mdbootstrap.com/) for my project. I have used list of `<a href>` tags for a list as below

```
<a  class="list-group-item list-group-item-action text-right  hoverlist "
 id="list-1"
 data-toggle="list"
 href="#list-1"
 role="tab"
 aria-controls="cat01">cat01<i class="fa fa-home"></i> </a>
```

This is the final preview

[image: SNAP]

What I wants to do is to **remove this blue color and then change color in to red.** So I have tried below code

```
.hoverlist{
background-color:red;
}
```

But nothings get changes. Could anyone please tell me why is that?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, there are two ways;

css properties are overridden from top to bottom:

The first is:
I don't understand whether the css implemented resides in an external file or not. But if it is place the link to the css file under the link for mdbootstrap. Like this:

```
<html>
<head>
<link href="mdbootsstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="your css file" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
</html>
```

or secondly, use the following code:

```
<a  class="list-group-item list-group-item-action text-right  hoverlist "
id="list-1"
data-toggle="list"
href="#list-1"
role="tab"
aria-controls="cat01" style="background-color: red">cat01<i class="fa fa-home"></i> </a>
```

Here, i have added style attribute to the link which will override all other css implementations.

See this pen: https://codepen.io/MansoorAhmed/pen/yLBKppw

Comment: Sorry this is just changing the background color. I just wants to change the color when user select the href. Thanks for the help

Comment: I have edited my codepen: See https://codepen.io/MansoorAhmed/pen/yLBKppw. Now, the list item will change color on hover.

Comment: Remember to add the `<style>...</style>` tag after the mdbootstrap css file link.